# Programmatically compiling source code using Roslyn

Tags: c#, compilation, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

So I've been trying to compile a piece of code programmatically with Roslyn. For some reasons the references that I add just don't end up in the Compilation class. So when I look at the referenced assembly after I use 'AddReferences', the list is empty. Hence, when I try to emit, I get "Object" not defined in the diagnostics. Can anyone point me to the problem?

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello"");            
    }
}
");
    string autoreferences = @"mscorlib.dll,System.Core.dll";
    List<string> usings = new List<string>();
    string netAssembliesDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
    var refs = new List<string>();
    foreach (string reference in autoreferences.Split(','))
        refs.Add(netAssembliesDirectory + "\\" + reference);


    CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("ConsoleTest")
        .WithOptions(
            new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication).WithUsings("System"))
        .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
    compilation.AddReferences(refs.Where(r => r != "").Select(r => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(r)));
    var er = compilation.Emit(@"C:\" + "ConsoleTest");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roslyn objects are immutable.

`compilation.AddReferences()` returns a new compilation instance with those references.
You're ignoring that new instance.

You need to call `Emit()` on the compilation instance that has your references.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of catched me by surprise that one. I guess I should have figured it out given the reflector pattern going on.

Comment: Do I have to parse the source code for the using clauses and add them using WithUsing? That's kind of strange to me.

Comment: @FarhadAlizadehNoori: No; `WithUsing` lets you add project-level using statements that apply to all files.